# Matlab/Simulink: linmod fails for subsystem

Tags: matlab, simulink

Given a simple Simulink model `Model` with a single input, a single output and a transfer function in between, I can use `linmod('Model')` to get the linear state space model. However, when I put the same model into a subsystem called `Subsystem` under `Model` and I issue `linmod('Model/Subsystem')` I get the following error:

```
Error using dlinmod (line 147)
Subsystem block does not have a parameter named 'SimulationStatus'
Error in linmod (line 59)
[varargout{1:max(1,nargout)}] = dlinmod(model, Ts, varargin{:}, Args);
```

I am using Matlab/Simulink R2014a. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`linmod` only works for Simulink models, not subsystems. The input and output points for the linearization are those corresponding to Inports and Outports blocks at the top-level of the model.

If you have [Simulink Control Design](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/simcontrol/), you should use [`linearize`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/ug/linearize.html), which is much more flexible and powerful (or the equivalent [linear analysis tool](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/ug/linearize-simulink-model.html)).